# Pneumatics + hydraulics =?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

OK, I guess I need to ask others to find the word that seems to be on the tip of my tongue. (brain cramp)

If I'm working on a system using mixed hydraulic and pneumatic subsystems, I want to say I'm working on a fluidic system, but fluidics seems to be limited to fluid logic and related. Can someone help me with the right word or phrase for this?

To go one step further, what if I'm working on a system that starts with a liquefied gas, a liquid at room temperature and under pressure, then handling the resulting gas after heat is added. I'd be handling liquid AND gas in the same system. I hesitate to call this cryogenics although I've previously worked with LN2 and liquid helium. Would I use the same name/word as original question above? Or a different name/word? What is that word/phrase?

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, you could just say fluid system, but I would still clarify it is both hydraulic and pneumatic. As an engineer or mechanic working with such a system, it would be very important to know that.

For the liquid-gas case, I would say it is a two-phase fluid system.